# Cannot understand solutions manual on integral $\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I work on
$$
\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-4}}\,dx.
$$
I set $u = x/2$ just like is is in the solution but I don't understand how it becomes $2\,du = 1/2\,dx$. Wouldn't it just be $2\,du = dx$ ?

Comment: It should be $2\,du=dx$. Throw the solution manual away.

Comment: Ok, so I continued the problem with 2du = dx and I come up with the solution arcsec(x/2) + C, but the solution is supposed to be 1/2arcsec(x/2) + C. Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it should indeed be $2\,du=dx$.

For $x>2$ you can write the primitive as $\frac{1}{2}\text{arcsec}\,(x/2)+C$ (note the one-half, you probably lost the inner derivative. Try do differentiate your answer, and you'll see). For $x<-2$, there will typically be a problem with sign if you write it like that.

Maybe, a better path to the solution is to put $u=\sqrt{x^2-4}$. It will give you
$$
\int\frac{1}{u^2+4}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{u}{2}+C
=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2-4}\Bigr)+C,
$$
valid for all $|x|>2$.

Answer (score 0):

Just make subsitution $x=2sec(t)$, so $dx=2sec(t)tan(t)dt$. Put these values in the integral. Use the identity $sec^2(t)-1=tan^2(t)$. So finally integral will look like this $$I=\int \frac{2sec(t)tan(t)dt}{(2sec(t))(2tan(t))}$$ Now 
$$I=\int \frac {dt}{2}=\frac {t}{2}+C $$ Now you can put back the value of $t$. So finally $$I=\frac {arcsec(\frac {x}{2})}{2}+C$$ Valid for all $|x|>2$